# How can I fix binutils fetch error

Tags: git, yocto, binutils, recipe

I use yocto 2.0.2 and I want to upgrade binutils to 2.29.1.

I already have 2.29.1 recipe.

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM="\
    file://COPYING;md5=59530bdf33659b29e73d4adb9f9f6552\
    file://COPYING.LIB;md5=9f604d8a4f8e74f4f5140845a21b6674\
    file://COPYING3;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
    file://COPYING3.LIB;md5=6a6a8e020838b23406c81b19c1d46df6\
    file://gas/COPYING;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
    file://include/COPYING;md5=59530bdf33659b29e73d4adb9f9f6552\
    file://include/COPYING3;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
    file://libiberty/COPYING.LIB;md5=a916467b91076e631dd8edb7424769c7\
    file://bfd/COPYING;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
    "

def binutils_branch_version(d):
    pvsplit = d.getVar('PV').split('.')
    return pvsplit[0] + "_" + pvsplit[1]

BINUPV = "${@binutils_branch_version(d)}"

UPSTREAM_CHECK_GITTAGREGEX = "binutils-(?P<pver>\d+_(\d_?)*)"

SRCREV = "90276f15379d380761fc499da2ba24cfb3c12a94"
SRC_URI = "\
     git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git;branch=binutils-${BINUPV}-branch;protocol=git \
     file://0003-configure-widen-the-regexp-for-SH-architectures.patch \
     file://0004-Point-scripts-location-to-libdir.patch \
     file://0005-Only-generate-an-RPATH-entry-if-LD_RUN_PATH-is-not-e.patch \
     file://0006-Use-libtool-2.4.patch \
     file://0007-Add-the-armv5e-architecture-to-binutils.patch \
     file://0008-don-t-let-the-distro-compiler-point-to-the-wrong-ins.patch \
     file://0009-warn-for-uses-of-system-directories-when-cross-linki.patch \
     file://0010-Fix-rpath-in-libtool-when-sysroot-is-enabled.patch \
     file://0011-Change-default-emulation-for-mips64-linux.patch \
     file://0012-Add-support-for-Netlogic-XLP.patch \
     file://0013-fix-the-incorrect-assembling-for-ppc-wait-mnemonic.patch \
     file://0014-Detect-64-bit-MIPS-targets.patch \
     file://0015-sync-with-OE-libtool-changes.patch \
"
S  = "${WORKDIR}/git"

do_configure_prepend () {
    rm -rf ${S}/gdb ${S}/libdecnumber ${S}/readline ${S}/sim
}
```

But when I doing build, bitbake occur fetch error.
Failed to fetch URL warning occur first, then after long time passed, occur the error.

But git clone is working. I can get binutils-gdb_2.29.1. by git clone.

Comment: Could You provide logs from failing *do_fetch* task ($ bitbake -c do_fetch binutils) ?

Comment: we need to see the log!